# Is chef_type mandatory for a node?

Tags: json, chef-infra, chef-attributes

In a project that uses Chef Server, we are using the following concepts:

- node
- role
- environment

The **environment** and **role** json files looks fine (they have `chef_type` and `json_class`):

- **ENV.json**

  ```
  {
      "name": "ENV",
      "chef_type": "environment",
      "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
      ...
      "cookbook_versions": {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```
- **my_role.json**

  ```
  {
      "name": "my_role",
      "chef_type": "role",
      "json_class": "Chef::Role",
      ...
      "run_list": [
          "role[my_role]",
          "recipe[my_recipe]"
      ]
  }
  ```

but the **node** looks like this (no `chef_type`, no `json_class`):

- **my.machine.json**

  ```
  {
      "chef_environment": "ENV",
      "name": "my.machine",
      "normal": {
         "key": "val"
      },    
      "run_list": [
           "role[my_role]"
      ]
  }
  ```

Is it a **real Chef node**?

And does is satisfy the following [**precedence**](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence)?
I supposed that if I had "normal" `"key":"value"` in node, role and environment, the following precedence (overwriting) order was applied: **node > role > environment**, but according to that documentation the precedence is ***role > environment > recipe*** and the recipe is in the same table cell as node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been slowly fixing the JSON loading code to not rely on the `json_class` auto-inflation bits. To the best of my knowledge `chef_type` was never actually used, but it may still be checked for by some of the testing code.

As for the precedence question: roles and envs can contain attributes at both the default and override levels. Override > normal > default. In general we recommend against the use of the normal level. It's not deprecated but we're moving in that direction (very slowly because we have many years of compat to think about).

Comment: But if the role, node and environment have the **same level**, which is the **overwriting order**? Is it **role > environment > node** (according to https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) ? Or is it as I supposed: **node > role > environment** (before reading the documentation)? My supposition was based on the intuition: I associated environment to a set of machines, the role to an application that runs on those machines and the node to a machine. And I believed that if I wanted to have a specific behavior per machine, I needed to add something in a node.

Comment: Nodes can only have data at the normal level and roles/envs can't use that level so conflicts aren't possible.